# How do I get Cloud9 to accept a "global" variable?

Tags: javascript, cloud9-ide

From using Cloud9 I have noticed that the editor accepts `$` as a global variable, but not other variables like `_`:

[image: Cloud9 screenshot]

Is there any way I can instruct the editor that it should accept the global underscore variable?

---

<sup>When I say "global" in this context, I mean "defined on the window object"</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This hasn't been answered yet so I figured I'd update everyone who's landing here from Google.

It's now possible to do this without explicitly defining globals at the top of every javascript file by using an .eslintrc file at the root of your project in C9. [You can see the documentation for this here on the eslint site.](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring)

For your use case, your .eslintrc file would look something like this:

```
{
    "globals": {
        "_": false
    }
}
```

Assigning it to `false` means that the linter will warn you when you try to overwrite the global. Setting it to `true` would allow reassignment of the global. Javascript would allow you to do it in either case, this setting only affects the linter behaviour.

Comment: This looks like a great solution if it works. I'll test it out when I get the chance.

Comment: This is a much better solution for me, compared to defining the globals at the top of each JS file. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I found a workaround on [support.cloud9ide.com](http://support.cloud9ide.com/entries/21712456-Referencing-other-js):

[image: Cloud9 screenshot]

By declaring `_` as a global variable in a comment I avoid the warnings, but that still means I need to modify every single javascript file in my project to appease a single text editor, which I don't like. I would much prefer an option where I could configure the *editor* to accept the underscore, in the same way it already accepts `$` by default.

Comment: This sounds like a great idea, so I sent it on to our research and development team for review and consideration in future developments (I work at Cloud9). Although we can't individually responded to or implement every request, please know that we do monitor suggestions quite closely for recurring themes. Please follow us on Twitter at http://twitter.com/cloud9ide or check out our blog at http://blog.c9.io for the latest improvements.

Comment: @IvarPruijn Any progress on that? :)